# How to create directory and text file and write content in file in media folder programmatically in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, programmatically, media

I tried to create directory and file and then put content in file programmatically but it does not work.
Here is my code in `sample.phtml`

```
<?php
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem */
    $filesystem = $om->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
    $directoryList = $om->get('Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface|\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write $writer */
    $media_url = getMediaBaseUrl();

    $writer = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite($media_url."module1/");
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\File\WriteInterface|\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\File\Write $file */
    $contents = "ddddddddddddddddddddddddddd";
    $relativeFileName = "sample.txt";
    $file = $writer->openFile($relativeFileName, 'w');

    try {
        $file->lock();
        try {
            $file->write($contents);
        }
        finally {
            $file->unlock();
        }
    }
    finally {
        $file->close();
    }

function getMediaBaseUrl() {
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $om */
    $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    /** @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager */
    $storeManager = $om->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    /** @var \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface|\Magento\Store\Model\Store $currentStore */
    $currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();
    return $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally, I got a solution for creating files and contents programmatically in Magento 2.

Here is a code

```
<?php
    try {
        $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $filesystem = $om->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
        $directoryList = $om->get('Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
        $media = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite($directoryList::MEDIA);
        $contents = "ddddddddddddddddddddddddddd";
        $media->writeFile("module1/sample.txt",$contents);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hello, If i have module xml file then what should i pass into getDirectoryWrite function?

Comment: you should pass same directory of magento. if your custom module then you have to create folder in media folder. you have to change name "module1" by your module name

Comment: ok thanks,but i have find another solution.

Comment: Good solution, but you should inject the dependency (only `\Magento\Framework\Filesystem` needed) into the constructor instead of using the object manager.
Instead of `$directoryList::MEDIA` you can use `\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA`.

Comment: @Dhrumin can u post the answer or post the link to the answer here?

Comment: this solution can work with xml file, tried and working good.

Answer (score 0):

**Url and directory are two different things**

You are using

```
$currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)
```

**You have to use**

```
$mediaPath=$filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
$writer = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(mediaPath."module1".DS);
```

**instead of**

```
$writer = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite($media_url."module1/");
```

Comment: this code does not work and thanks for the help but I got a solution and post answered