# Generate custom xml file programmatically

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2 how can I Generate xml file programmatically.

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226705/how-to-create-directory-and-text-file-and-write-content-in-file-in-media-folder

Comment: Hi Team,I;m able to create the xml